# Sign up routerLink doesn't work [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms

I have a problem signup link doesnt work I don't why script seems correct but does not working can some one give me an idea by the way the signup link work correctly in app-component

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card card-container">

      <form
        *ngIf="!isLoggedIn"
        name="form"
        (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()"
        #f="ngForm"
        novalidate
      >
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input
            type="text"/>

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"/>            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
        </form>
      <div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
        Create an account?<a  href="/register" class="nav-link" routerLink="register">Sign Up</a>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you share the routing file?

Comment: That's solved thank you I just added [routerLink]="['/register']" instead of routerLink="register"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need href when using routerlink. Try this instead :

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn">
        Create an account?<a   class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/register']">Sign Up</a>
      </div>
```

Check out routerlink doc for more info: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

Comment: That's working but why routerLink="register" doesn't work isn't the same?

Comment: It should work too. I can't remember exactly the syntax but I think it's more like : `routerLink="/register"` always with leading slash

Comment: yeah I missed / but in other pages I use it without slash & it works. btw Thank you for your help